# Conversion of anonymous XML datatypes to named datatypes

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have the following snippet from an XML Schema:

```
<xs:element name="textSelection">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="path" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="color" minOccurs="0">             
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="yellow"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="light blue"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="orange"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="fucsia"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="contentRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

As one can see there are two anonymous datatypes.
One being a `<xs:complexType>` with 3 elements inside and the other being `<xs:simpleType>`which has 5 enumerations.

Since this is not a very good solution, namely both being anonymous I tried to convert them to named datatypes and this is what I thought of:

```
<xs:complexType name="textSelection">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="path" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="color" type="color" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="contentRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="color">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="yellow"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="light blue"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="orange"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="fucsia"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

**So now to my actual questions:**

1. Did I do the conversion correctly or did I made any mistakes?
2. Is it OK for `<xs:element name="color" type="color"
   minOccurs="0"/>` to have both the name and the type of `color`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the following XSD that reflects your named type conversion is correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="textSelection">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="path" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="color" type="color" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="contentRef" type="textSelection" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="textSelection">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="path" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="color" type="color" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="contentRef" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="color">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="yellow"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="light blue"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="orange"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="fucsia"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

And, yes, it is ok to have an element and a type with the same name.  Many conventions would avoid that in some manner, however, such as using `colorType` for the type, for example.